# Can you change the SecurityTokenService's AlgorithmSuite programmatically?

Tags: java, java-metro-framework, sts-securitytokenservice, wsit

I have to consume a service which has this snippet in the documentation:

> ...you may need to release an update that changes
>   the configured STS URL to the v1.3 production end point, **and** changes the AlgorithmSuite on the STS binding to SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15

Here's how I do my request:

```
IService service = new Service(new URL(getServiceWSDL())).getWS2007FederationHttpBindingIService();

((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY, getCertificate());
((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(PRIVATEKEY_PROPERTY, getPrivateKey());
((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(STS_NAMESPACE, getSTSNamespace());
((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(STS_PORT_NAME, getSTSPortName());
((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(STS_SERVICE_NAME, getSTSServiceName());
((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(STS_ENDPOINT, getSTSEndpoint());
((WSBindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(STS_WSDL_LOCATION, getSTSWDSLLocation());

service.operation(...);
```

When the request executes, it authenticates first with the STS then does the actual request. How do I change the AlgorithmSuite for the STS part of the request?

I tried declaring it in the WSDL of the STS but I don't think the request actually loads anything using that WSDL.

Comment: Or perhaps change the AlgorithmSuite on per-request basis?

Comment: Any updates on this post?

Comment: @t_godd You can't change it programmatically. If you have to change it, you have to modify the WSDL before it is loaded. I just manually modified the actual WSDL that I was using but you can do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change it programmatically. If you have to change it, you have to modify the WSDL before it is loaded. I just manually modified the actual WSDL that I was using but you can do that programmatically.